# How To DIsplay Specific Product Categories from WooCommerce in flutter

Tags: flutter, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am working on a flutter woocommerce app and I need help trying to display just a few specific product categories from Woocommerce rather than just displaying All Categories as in my code below. I have tried assigning multiple values to the index but it doesn't work. Please, how do I go about it?

**Here is my code below**

```
Widget _buildCategoryList(List<categoryModel.Category> categories) {
    return Container(
      height: 120,
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: categories.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var data = categories[index];
          return SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  // Navigator.push(
                  //     context,
                  //     MaterialPageRoute(
                  //         builder: (context) => ProductPage(
                  //               categoryId: data.categoryId,
                  //             )));
                },
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top:10),
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: data.image != null
                          ? ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                              child: Image.network(
                                data.image.url,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            )
                          : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: Palette.backgroundColor,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              offset: Offset(0, 0),
                              blurRadius: 2,
                            )
                          ]),
                    ),
                    Text(
                          data.categoryName.toString(),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 13,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                ),
              ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Here is my Categories Model just in case it might help or need a little tweaking**

```
class Category {
  int categoryId;
  String categoryName;
  String categoryDesc;
  int parent;
  Image image;

  Category({
    this.categoryId,
    this.categoryName,
    this.categoryDesc,
    this.image,
  });

  Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    categoryId = json["id"];
    categoryName = json["name"];
    categoryDesc = json["description"];
    parent = json["parent"];
    image = json["image"] != null ? Image.fromJson(json['image']) : null;
  }
}

class Image {
  String url;
  Image({this.url});
  Image.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    url = json['src'];
  }
}
```

Comment: What the JSON result is ?

Comment: @cahyo 
The above code actually works fine.
And how do I check the JSON result for this? I'm still a beginner in flutter. Thanks?

Answer (score 3):

Add this before returning the listview:

```
categories.where((item) => item.id != 'categoryId' && item.id != 'categoryId').toList();
```